# JSDoc does not recognize ES6 Class

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, apt, es6-class, jsdoc3

I installed JSDoc from apt on Ubuntu 20.04 using `jsdoc-toolkit` and it does not recognize my ES6 class. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version in apt provided by `jsdoc-toolkit` is an old version, [JSDoc Toolkit 2.4.0](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsdoc-toolkit/).

Use `npm install -g jsdoc` to globally install JSDoc 3, which [supports ES6 Classes](https://jsdoc.app/howto-es2015-classes.html).